# how to record audio from output device without sharing the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJS project with a feature that needs to record the system audio output (the audio output of the device, not the user's microphone input).

I know that I can use `navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia()` to get a stream from the system audio output. However, this approach requires obtaining the authorization to stream the whole screen, which would lead to some user refusing to grant the authorization.

Is there any way to record the system audio output with less intrusive authorization from the user ?

edit to be clearer: The idea isn't to have no authorization from the user at all, but only audio related authorization (`getDisplayMedia()` requires authorization to stream the screen).

Comment: Record audio from the _speaker?_  Do you mean you want to record any audio coming out the speaker, regardless of what the source of that audio is? Record the music I'm playing, record the audio from a video I'm playing? Record the audio from the Zoom call I'm on? (If that's the case I sure _hope_ there's no way to do it without getting authorization from the user)

Comment: Yes, i want to record any audio coming out of the speaker. The question isn't about having no authorization from the user, but only audio authorization (the user wouldn't comprehend why an authorization to record the screen is needed)

Comment: I updated the title and content a bit, since "speaker" isn't really what you're after, but rather the audio output of the device.

Comment: @disinfor : thank you for the edit. However, I rolled back the change on the title as the focus of the question is about recording without streaming the whole screen, not getting authorization (which result from the recording function)

Comment: @kirua "how to record audio from output device" is not specific enough - you are trying to record the audio only **and** also ask for user authorization that doesn't include the screen, only audio. If what I had didn't meet that requirement, I would update your title to reflect - Audio only, while obtaining permission for audio only.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` method to list all the input and output media devices available.

If an audio device is available then use

```js
MediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true
});
```

As for bypassing authorization, that would be almost impossible with most browsers due to security reasons, the users will have to agree to the fact that you will be recording their speaker.

But with the above method, the request to record audio would be
less scary for the user than a permission asking to record the entire screen.

Documentation links:

- [enumerateDevices](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/enumerateDevices)
- [gerUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, getUserMedia() only allow to get a stream from an input source, not from an output source. By speaker, I mean the audio output device, not the user speaking (I have clarified my question about it)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use useRef hook function for your purpose

```
const [stream, setStream] = useState(null);
const videoRef = useRef();

const startCapture = async () => {
    try {
      const captureStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: {
          mandatory: {
            chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
            chromeMediaSourceId: 'screen:0',
          },
        },
      });
      setStream(captureStream);
      videoRef.current.srcObject = captureStream;
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error accessing media devices: ', err);
    }
};
```